# Stretch button height to fill parent td, even when text wrap occurs in tr, increasing td height

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the codepin: https://codepen.io/josh5555s/pen/zYJyWbR

The issue looks like this:

[image: html table with buttons]

I want the buttons to be 100% of td height even if the text wrap has increased the td height, as seen in the first row of the above example.

I have looked through many Stack Overflow posts on similar topics, but nothing has worked for this specific situation.

I've tried setting both parent and child elements to `height: 100%`

I've also tried setting the parent td to `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` and the child button to `align-items: stretch;`

I  am wondering if something about the td element doesn't follow the same rules as the div, which most Stack Overflow examples are using.

html:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>word word word</td>
      <td>
        <button>x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>word</td>
      <td>
        <button>x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  
}

td {
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use absolute positioning to stretch the buttons.

Hope you're using `table` to display tabular data, otherwise you'd be better with `grid` or `flex`.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  position:relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute; top:0; left:0;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>word word word</td>
    <td>
      <button>x</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>word</td>
    <td>
      <button>x</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I was starting to think it wasn't possible... Thank you.

Comment: It does look like the absolute positioning breaks the responsive font size for those cells, which is unfortunate. I am currently using font-size: 2.5vw; Is there any way around that?

Comment: @JoshuaS, I don't see any `font` rules in your example, so it's not clear to me what are you talking about. Actually, positioning never affects font, probably it's something else. Just in case, `2.5vw` is effectively `2.5%` of the viewport width and `position` rule cannot change it.

Comment: You were right, it was something else. Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score -1):

`Button` parent element `<td>` default `height: 100%`, so set `<td>` `height` manually.

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  
}

td {
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}

button {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>word word word</td>
      <td>
        <button>x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>word</td>
      <td>
        <button>x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution hard-codes the td height, but I need that to responsively expand or contract based on dynamic text content.